# How to retrieve Json Data and display on Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, chart.js

Hello everyone I am trying to retrieve some data from `data.php` then allowing my `app.js` to display the data via Chartjs.

The data that I want to display is `feedbackrowcount` & `complainrowcount`
Which I already did a query to retrieve what I want from mysql.

Below is my `data.php` that does the query and the json data

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customercaremodule');


if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query1 = sprintf("SELECT FC_Category FROM fbcomplain where FC_Category ='Feedback'");
$Countsql1 = "SELECT count(FC_ID) AS total FROM fbcomplain WHERE FC_Category ='Feedback'";

//execute query
$result1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
$res1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$Countsql1);
$value1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1);
$feedbackrowcount = $value1['total'];
//loop through the returned data
$data1 = array();
foreach ($result1 as $row) {
    $data1[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result1->close();


//query to get data from the table
$query2 = sprintf("SELECT FC_Category FROM fbcomplain where FC_Category ='Complain'");
$Countsql2 = "SELECT count(FC_ID) AS total FROM fbcomplain WHERE FC_Category ='Complain'";
//execute query
$result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
$res2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$Countsql2);
$value2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2);
$complainrowcount = $value2['total'];


//loop through the returned data
$data2 = array();
foreach ($result2 as $row) {
    $data2[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result2->close();


//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data1);
print json_encode($data2);
print json_encode($feedbackrowcount);
print json_encode($complainrowcount);
?>
```

This is `app.js` that display the chart. I believe the **Data:** is the key to not being able to display the chart on my webpage. Please help me to write the statement needed to retrieve data from data.php to app.js. Thank you so much!

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/customercare/data.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

var oilCanvas = document.getElementById("oilChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var feedbackvscomplainData = {
    labels: [
        "Feedback",
                "Complain"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data:
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                                "#FF6300"
            ]
        }]
};




var pieChart = new Chart(oilCanvas, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: feedbackvscomplainData
});
```

Comment: you can do ajax with js

Comment: I think your `data.php` is fine. I am no JQuery user, but according to the documentation, you haven't sent **any** request to your PHP file, thus ending up with no data. Try to read this and tell us if it can help. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/